# How To Query Rows From A Cursor Returned From A Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I've got the following existing procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE pmm$AppUser_GetApprover_KFGZ7Q(
    ReleaseRequestID INT )
AS
  RefCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN

  OPEN RefCursor FOR 
    SELECT
       U.*
    FROM pmm$PmmReleaseRequest R
    INNER JOIN dbo$ManagedEntity ME
    ON ME.ManagedEntityID = R.ManagedSystemID
    INNER JOIN dbo$SmartRuleAssetCache SRC
    ON SRC.AssetID = ME.AssetID
    INNER JOIN dbo$UserGroup_SmartRule_Role GSR
    ON GSR.SmartRuleId = SRC.SmartRuleId
    AND GSR.RoleId    IN (2,3)
    INNER JOIN dbo$AppUser_UserGroup UG
    ON UG.GroupID           = GSR.UserGroupId
    AND UG.UserID          <> R.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo$AppUser U ON UG.UserID = U.UserID
    WHERE R.ReleaseRequestID = ReleaseRequestID;

    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RefCursor);
  END;
```

I would like to call this from a `Trigger` and query the `Cursor` returned using some `Where` clauses to further refine the results.

Most ideally I would like to put the records in a temporary table.

I can't seem to find any documentation on **the best way** to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish but it looks likely that you're going down the wrong path.  Technically, you could create a global temporary table that has the same definition as the `dbo$AppUser` table.  You could loop in your trigger, fetch from the cursor and write a row to the temporary table.  Then you could run a query against the temporary table.  But that's very inefficient.  My guess is that you really want a view rather than a procedure here.  If you're looking at a row-level trigger on any of the objects in the query, you also have mutating table issues.

Comment: I'm querying the results of the above proc for the sake of inserting some of the columns in another table. This an existing system I'm working on. I'm a bit limited in what I can change.

Comment: Even pulling out a row and assigning it to variables would be sweet!

Comment: This [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/321911?tstart=0) has some good information on how to process an output ref cursor, search on "358102 Aug 12, 2005 9:53 AM" and look at the example using procedure test..

Comment: You can't add `WHERE` clauses or conditions to refine the result. The cursor is what it is when it's opened. If you need different data, open a different cursor. Note that if your trigger is a row trigger (i.e. contains `FOR EACH ROW`) and the trigger is defined on any of the tables mentioned in the query above you're going to have further problems. Best of luck.

Comment: I ended up moving the query in the procedure into the trigger. It seems stupid that I can't compartmentalize these things easily.

Comment: You can "compartmentalize" code easily enough.  It looks like you're trying to do so in the hardest possible way which is causing some confusion (particularly when you seem to be trying to make Oracle work like SQL Server).  That's why I suggested a view rather than a procedure.  Or perhaps even a pipelined table function.

Comment: I'm actually translating SQL sever scripts to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

> Not directly, no.
>
> A SYS_REFCURSOR is a pointer to a result-- the only thing you can do
>   with that is to fetch the data. You can't modify the result set. However the best 
>   way workaround for this is to put the data into some king of Temp
>   table( most preferred is GTT Global temporary table) and then utilize
>   it to do all the validations in Trigger.
>
> Hope below snippet is useful for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_cur(
    p_out OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_out FOR SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 15;
  -- Here dummy tab can be any temp table or GTT
  INSERT INTO DUMMY_TAB
  SELECT  LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 15;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <Trigger_name> 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON <TYABLE_NAME> 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
--<variable declarations>
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('Your code for data Manipulations');
   --SELECT FROM GTT/ Temp table and all the manipulations required   
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code is missing some things. I just see a shell for a procedure (I can't modify the existing header to include `p_out OUT sys_refcursor`), and another shell for a trigger that prints a same string for each row. It's a general reply, not quite an answer or solution. Thanks though.